# Add specific items to cart on click

Tags: javascript, html, cart

I want the cart to add the item that the `Add to cart` button relates to. Can you also please explain the reason behind it not working. Currently it is only adding the first product.
Here is the HTML:

```
<p class="name">Playstation 4 console (Black)</p>
<p class="pricetitle">Price: <span id="price">1899</span> AED</p>
<form>
    <button type="button" onclick="addToCart()">Add to cart</button>
</form>

<p class="name">Xbox one console (Black)</p>
<p class="pricetitle">Price: <span id="price">1800</span> AED</p>
<form>
    <button type="button" onclick="addToCart()">Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

and here is the JavaScript:

```
const name = document.querySelectorAll(".name");
const price = document.querySelectorAll("#price");
const button = document.querySelectorAll("button");
const cart = []
const addToCart = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        cart.push(name[i].innerText)
        cart.push(parseInt(price[i].innerText))
    }
    console.log(cart)
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I assume this HTML is being dynamically created. If so the SKU could be stored in a data attribute on the button. Do you control the HTML?

Comment: Yes i do, this is just some javascript practice to up my knowledge a little bit

Comment: Try i < 2 in your for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, where we use `data-` attributes in the html. To help us when we load the cart.

```js
let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

const cart = [];

for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
  let button = buttons[i];
  console.log(button);
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    console.clear();
    console.log(event.target);
    console.log(event.target.dataset.productSku);
    cart.push( event.target.dataset.productSku );
    console.log(cart)    
  });
}
```

```html
<p class="name">Playstation 4 console (Black)</p>
<p class="pricetitle">Price: <span id="price">1899</span> AED</p>
<button data-product-sku="ps4black">Add to cart</button>


<p class="name">Xbox one console (Black)</p>
<p class="pricetitle">Price: <span id="price">1800</span> AED</p>
<button data-product-sku="xboxoneblack">Add to cart</button>

<div id="cart"></div>
```